# Chain rule of multiple variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

I am having a hard time understanding the following:

I need to have $\frac{dR}{dS}$, if I am given the following equations in terms of $x$ and $y$.

$R(x,y)= x^3 + xy$ and $S(x,y)=6x^2y$.

I was thinking of using the following: 
$\frac{dR}{dS} = \frac{\partial R}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dS} + \frac{\partial R}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dS}$. Is this correct?

For example if I took the derivative of $S$ with respect to $x$, in order to get the reciprocal of $\frac{dx}{dS}$, wouldn't I end up with the term $\frac{dy}{dx}$ because of the chain rule? I think I'm mostly confused on obtaining the terms $\frac{dx}{dS}$ and $\frac{dy}{dS}$ if I only have one equation involving $S$.

Comment: Is $S=100$ a constant?

Comment: Woops, that part was used earlier the problem as a constraint. I can edit that out. I'm just figuring out what $\frac{dR}{dS}$ in general is now.

Comment: Just double-checking, so for $\frac{dS}{dt} = 12xy + 6x^2\frac{dy}{dx}$? Is there any way to solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$?